# Angular 2 - select binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to select in `<select>` an option which I defined in component. But when I want to print this in console I get undefined. My code:

component.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Select option:</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
            <option *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item">{{ item.display }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" (click)="showOption()">Show selected option</button>
```

component.ts:

```
selectedOption: any;

sortOptions = [
    {
        value: 'option1',
        display: 'First option'
    },
    {
        value: 'option2',
        display: 'Second option'
    }
];

showOption(): void {
    console.log(this.selectedOption.value);
}
```

When I try print `console.log(this.selectedOption.value);` I get "undefined" and when I try to print console.log(this.selectedOption) I get "[option Option]"

I don't know how to resole it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `[ngValue]` instead `[value]`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of options" [ngValue]="item">
     {{item.display}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works, thanks. What is a different between value and ngValue?

Comment: There's no documentation which explain in details ngValue, but if you want to use objects in option you have to do it via `[ngValue]` for the rest cases you can use `[value]`

Comment: And what if I use ReactiveFormsModule instead of FormsModule — so I have `formControlName` instead of the `ngModel` — what should I do to make Angular to select `selectedOption`? Now I have `options` array and `selectedOption` is one of this array items... but Angular is not making this option as selected :(

Comment: It stays the same just replace `[(ngModel)]` with `formControlName` and it should works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this :

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of sortOptions" [value]="item.id">
     {{item.display}}
   </option>
</select>
```

**[value]** for string values and **[ngValue]** for all types